# Thyristor voltage regulator with different fireing angle for each period with simulink

Tags: voltage-regulator, simulation, matlab, thyristor

First of all I'm really low with EE so please, go easy on me. As home assigment we have to design **Thyristor voltage regulator** in **simulink**. It should run for 5 periods with different thyristor fireing angle for each period (30*, 60*, 90*, 120*, 150*). I managed to build it for single fireing angle with some matlab tutorials ([first](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ug/introducing-power-electronics.html), [second](http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/thyristor.html)) and school book. The problem is I have no idea how to make it fire at different fireing angle each period (**I mean, dynamically change the fiering angle for each period during single simulation, ex. 30* for first period, 60* for next etc.**). Any tips how to do it?

The circuit and parameters:

[image: circuit]

Here are parameters:

- AC Voltage source:

  - Peak amplitude (V): 230
  - Phase (deg): 0
  - Frequency (Hz): 60
  - Sample time: 0
  - Measurements: None
- Pulse Generator

  - Pulse type: Time based
  - Time (t): Use simulation time
  - Amplitude: 1
  - Period (secs): 1/60
  - Pulse Width (% of period): 1
  - Phase delay (secs): (1/60) + (1/60) *1
- Pulse Generator1

  - Pulse type: Time based
  - Time (t): Use simulation time
  - Amplitude: 1
  - Period (secs): 1/60
  - Pulse Width (% of period): 1
  - Phase delay (secs): (1/60)+(1/120)+(1/160) *1
- Thyristor 1, Thryistor 2

  - Resistance Ron (Ohms): 0.001
  - Inductance Lon (H): 0
  - Forward voltage Vf (V): 0.8
  - Snubber resistance Rs (Ohms): 500
  - Snubber capacitance Cs (F): 250e-9
- Series RLC Branch

  - Branch type: RL
  - Resistance (Ohms): 100
  - Inductance (H): 0.2

*1 According to first matlab tutorial the 1/160 should give fireing angle of 135 degrees. The (1/120) is 180 degree delay. I have no idea what 1/60 is. However that math works for my case.

**@edit 21.05.2015**
My teacher mentoined about vector input (tho no details). How to add vector input into thyristors (so the fireing angle is changed during simulation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I figured it out. I also measure a lot of things so the circuit can be a bit messy.
[image: the circuit]

The **repeating sequence stair** with **multiport switch**es controls the fiering angle. The parameters are:

- Repeating sequence stair:

  - Vector of output values: [1 2 3 4 5]
  - Sample time: 1/60 (its equal to the source's frequency but I'm not sure if that matters)

Every port of **multiport switch** is connected to pulse generator with different fireing angle. All but one parameters are the same among generators:

- Pulse generators:

  - Amplitude: 1
  - Period: 1/60
  - Pulse Width: 1%
  - Phase delay - the only parameter that differs:

    - For generator 0,2,3,4,5: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 (generator 0 -> t1, generator 2 -> t2 etc)
    - For generator 6,1,7,8,9: 120 + t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 (generator 6 -> 120+t1, etc)

Where

- t1 = 1/720 (30* angle)
- t2 = 1/360 (60* angle)
- t3 = 1/240 (90* angle)
- t4 = 1/180 (120* angle)
- t5 = 1/144 (150* angle)

The source, thyristors and RLC branch parameters are equal to those in first post.

As you can see below the received current and voltage (the first 2 plots) change as demanded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. 1/(f)=time period of wave of frequency f
2. 1/(2*f)= time of half wave=Pi rad=180 Deg
3. if f=60 Hz then half wave period 1/(2*60)=1/120=8.33 mSe
4. 1/160=6.25 mSec
5. firing angle =6.25*180/8.33=135 deg
6. means Matlab  Factor =1/((2*f)*(180/firing angle))

vtingole

Comment: thanks for explanation of the math, however still i dont know how to change fiering angle dynamically during simulation :/

Comment: perhaps ..an increment and conditional loop would do..